# Weblogic 11g Indefinite Lockout

Tags: weblogic11g

Is there a way to enable indefinite lockout in Weblogic 11g?
I only see `UserLockoutManagerMBean.LockoutDuration` which is between `0` and `30` minutes.

To clarify: Indefinite lockout as in account can only be unlocked by an admin.

Comment: I am not sure if there is an indefinite lockout (unless you write your own provider). But 30 minutes is not the max, it's just the default. For instance, you can put in something like `129600` so the user is locked out for 90 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Oracle Support, there is no indefinite lockout. However, the solution proposed is to set the lockout duration to a very large value.

> The maximum threshold value is 9223372036854775807 minutes which
>   comes around (17536635926176.287109) years.